# CSS doesn't seem to affect TD structure

Tags: html, css, css-position, html-table

I'm coding a quick site for a school project and I'm extremely rusty *hangs head in shame*. I can't seem to get the width to affect the  tags or center the text in them.

I have no idea why but if you could explain to me what I have to do to get the links on the nav bar centered and for the image to sit atop the loading text and act as a title. The loading should be centered btw but calc() doesn't like me ;~;

http://jsfiddle.net/MasterWhipper/6Z6z6/

```
<div id="navBar">
    <table id="navText">
        <tr>
            <td><div class="navTd"><a href="">Home</a></div></td>
            <td width="396px">Loading</td>
            <td><div class="navTd"><a href="">Donate</a></div></td>
            <td><div class="navTd"><a href="">About Us</a></div></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y7OE90F.png" class="titleIMG"/>
</div>
```

*Note: would it be easier to use a list for what I'm trying to do?*

Comment: the `width` attribute takes a number, of pixels - drop the `px` at the end for starters

Comment: Use `table-layout: fixed;` but don't use `table` for this, use `ul` and `li` with `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once again, people are professing their hatred of table. Don't worry about it.

Here, I made it work with tables. Three things I changed:

1. Set the table to `table-layout: fixed;`
2. Put your `navTd` class on the td, not the div. Otherwise you're telling the div to take a certain size of the td, not the td to take a certain size of the table
3. Removed the px to `396px`. The width attribute does not use CSS syntax. You may want to use CSS for the width though, just to be more HTML5-zealous-friendly.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6z6/3/

Comment: Awesome this is what I needed but thanks to all for the other methods which I will consider next time I'm making a navigation bar XD If you're feeling generous why isn't the image floating above the loading text if I have it as absolute and a lower z-index?

Comment: @user3176562 I'm not super familiar with z-index but first of all I think higher values are above, not the other way around. Anyway, I solved it by removing any mention of z-index, and putting the `<img>` tag of the image before the table. http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6z6/6/

Comment: Elements displayed as tables in CSS (`display: table` and `table-row` and `table-cell`)? Awesome, I love them. Compatibility IE8+ (fiddle from OP is IE9+ so that'd have been fine). HTML data tables? The most semantic way of displaying data tables. HTML **layout** tables? Terrible and it've been for years in most cases. In 2014, in all cases except legacy systems and when `colspan / rowspan` would be needed (doesn't exist in CSS)

Comment: @FelipeAls I just want to act a bit as the counterweight to the 'float: left' evangelists. He wants a menu that is a single row. That's the complete opposite of what floats are meant to do.

Comment: If done in CSS, perfect. In HTML? Terrible in 2014. That's my point. EDIT: only using `float: left` is a lack of skill, I'm also OK with that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using table structure use `ul`, `li` tags for navigation... You can easily style them :)

```
   <div id="navBar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li>Loading</li>
        <li><a href="">Donate</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
     </ul>

     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y7OE90F.png" class="titleIMG"/>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best idea it is to use the `HTML5 nav` tag, it has been thought for navigations menu as yours:

```
<nav>
<a href="/html/">Home</a> |
<a href="/css/">Loading</a> |
<a href="/js/">Donate</a> |
<a href="/jquery/">About us</a>
</nav>
```

It is a solution that fits with your problem and plus it is the current standard! You will not have problem with CSS.

Here you are more info about `HTML5 nav` tag:

http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Comment: Thanks for the info I willy surely do this next time :)

Answer (score 0):

first things first...you **don't need** `<div class="navTd">` inside a `<td>`

Assign everything to `<td>` and that would do.
Then, instead of using `calc` (*its still not cross-browser*), use `display:inline-block;` to allocate width to the `td`

```
 #navText > td {
    display:inline-block;
    z-index: 3;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6z6/4/)